# Drupal Form API : How to pass additional data back to the form after it is been submitted

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have created a form in Drupal using its API. The theme is overridden by a template. In the template, I want to show errors where the form exists, I do not want to show the error using drupal's `form_set_error()` because it shows the error in a fixed default area of the page.

This is my implementation of `hook_form()`

```
function newsletter_box($form, &$form_state)
{
    $form = array();

    $form["newsletter-email"] = array(
        "#type" => "textfield",
        "#maxlength" => 32,
        "#title" => "Your Email"
    );

    $form['send-email'] = array(
        "#type" => "submit",
        "#value" => t("Join Our Newsletter!")
    );

    return $form;
}
```

And this is my implementation of `hook_submit()`

```
function newsletter_box_submit($form, &$form_state)
{
    if( !filter_var($form_state['values']["newsletter-email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) )
    {
        $form_state['build_info']['args'] = ['form-error' => t("Email not formatted correctly.") ];
// NOTE: here is the place where the error is set, rather I use to set a new variable, but this variable is not available in my template. Why?
    }

    $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
    drupal_form_submit("newsletter_box", $form_state);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest adding the variable by implementing a hook_preprocess, and add the error message into form rather than form_state.

Example:

```
// Set in newsletter_box_submit or newsletter_box_validate
$form['#form_error'] = t("Email not formatted correctly.");

/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK().
 */
function [module_name]_preprocess_newsletter_box(&$vars) {
  $form = $vars['form'];
  $error_message = $form['#form_error'];
  // Use $error_message in template.
}
```

It feels like a hack though, strongly recommend theming the form the Drupal way.

Comment: I have used Form API. So that is not a hack. Why should it be a hack? There isn't a proper way for doing this. So strange.

Comment: I'd say this answer arguably _is_ the right way to do it. There are other permutations you could use but they all involve unpicking what's already there in a less then elegant fashion. @MostafaTalebi I'd recommend looking at the [Inline Form Errors](https://www.drupal.org/project/ife) module to see how it accomplishes something quite similar to what I think you're doing

Comment: @MostafaTalebi it feels that way to me because any developer working on the site now needs to be aware of this implementation and take care not to override it :) It also doesn't support multiple errors in the current iteration, though that's easier to modify.